# Fast clicking the bootstrap delete icon twice results in breakage of the 1st delete cycle

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Fast clicking the bootstrap delete icon twice results in breakage of the 1st delete cycle, tool-tip doesn't hide on mouseout and few other hyperlinks and mouse events stop working.

I have a set of contacts displayed in a list on an overlay, each of it with a bootstrap delete icon besides it which displays a tool-tip on mouse hover. for the delete icons, neither are we using `button`, nor anchor tag `a`, we are using bootstrap icons which act as the links for click event. Please suggest how to disable the 2nd click for them. Fast clicking the delete icon twice, disrupts the 1st delete cycle, causing other hyperlinks like delete icons and tool-tips on other contact records to be disabled and all other mouse events to be disabled, freezes the delete icon (which is no more visible on mouseover) and open overlay hyperlink icon.
Tried several options like:

- Explicitly deactivating mouse events on row after 1st click of delete icon using `angular.element('.deleteIconClass').css('pointer-events','none');`
  and activating mouse events on row after success or failure of delete AJAX call using `angular.element('.deleteConfigIcon').css('pointer-events','auto');` respectively.
- Calling angular UI grid refresh on overlay so as to hide the retained tool-tip and show back the delete icons on hover over delete icons on each row.
- Explicitly calling mouseout or mouseleave and mouseover or mouseenter events to respectively hide and show the tool-tips on delete icons of each row.

None of the above are working satisfactorily. Am I missing something in the design or coding? Kindly let me know if any other information is required as it is an already existing code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Fast clicking the bootstrap delete icon twice results in breakage of the 1st delete cycle

Didn't quiet catch the rest if your question but If you're trying to prevent the an action from perormining more than one, you need to disable it on click.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="clicked()" ng-disabled="hasClicked">click me</button>

$scope.clicked = function(){
     $scope.hasClicked = true;
     someLongTask()
          .finally(function(){
              $scope.hasClicked = false;
          });
}
```

you can use the same to disable all other buttons.

If you're using `a` with `href`  you may want to refer to this directive to prevent click on an href that is disabled (eatClickIf).

https://gist.github.com/bcabanes/677305a013660ae7d55e

Comment: Neither are we using `button`, nor anchor tag `a`, we are using bootstrap icons which act as links for click. Please suggest how to disable the 2nd click for them.

Comment: <span ng-click="!hasClicked && clicked()"><i class="some-icon-class"></i><span>

clicked() will only fire if hasClicked is false; you can still use above code to mark hasClicked as true when doing some task and mark it false after done

Comment: plunker for you: https://plnkr.co/edit/IhPE31YPnf2SZ0Q0rt2J?p=preview

Now matter how many times you click an icon.. it will always start and done before it starts another. (check console log)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, I tried the above solution, unfortunately it isn't quite working yet. When we click the mouse extremely quickly in succession, the 2nd mouse click on the delete icon is possible and not disabled yet. I am setting `hasClicked = true` as soon as the delete function is called and the control enters in there and setting it back to false once we get the success/failure promise object data from delete AJAX call. Tried the `<button ng-disabled="hasClicked">` approach too, but none of them seem to be too fast enough to prevent the 2nd mouse click! Please help.